# How to make Jenkins rememeber the varaiable and its value when restarting jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

- I'm running the following Jenkinsfile
- This Jenkins file allow the user to select values like version and quality of the build
- This Jenkins file allow the user to select values like applications to be selected during the installation of the product (MSI file with features to select inside it)

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'version_choice',
            choices: 'Trunk\nV25.0.0\nV24.0.0',
            description: 'Select a version (Trunk or Release No.)')
        choice(
            name: 'quality_choice',
            choices: 'latestGreen\nHotfix\nReleased\nInternal',
            description: 'Select a quality')
        choice(
            name: 'protocol_choice',
            choices: 'HTTPS',
            description: 'Select Protocol, HTTPS (Secured) or HTTP (Non-Secured)')
        booleanParam(
            name: 'fuel',
            defaultValue: false,
            description: '')
        booleanParam(
            name: 'aloha_kitchen',
            defaultValue: false,
            description: '')
        booleanParam(
            name: 'data_event_publisher',
            defaultValue: false,
            description: '')
        booleanParam(
            name: 'catalog_exporter',
            defaultValue: false,
            description: '')
        booleanParam(
            name: 'signal_r',
            defaultValue: false,
            description: '')
        booleanParam(
            name: 'fiscal',
            defaultValue: false,
            description: '')
        booleanParam(
            name: 'notification_server',
            defaultValue: false,
            description: '')
        choice(
            name: 'eft_simulator_choice',
            choices: ['MTX', 'EPS'],
            description: 'Select EFT Simulator')
        booleanParam(
            name: 'external_services',
            defaultValue: false,
            description: 'Ext. Services Simulator')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Initial') {
            steps {
                script {
                    APPLICATIONS = "";

                    if ("${params.fuel}" == "true") {
                        APPLICATIONS += ',Fuel';
                    }
                    if ("${params.aloha_kitchen}" == "true") {
                        APPLICATIONS += ',AlohaKitchen';
                    }
                    if ("${params.data_event_publisher}" == "true") {
                        APPLICATIONS += ',DataEventPublisher';
                    }
                    if ("${params.catalog_exporter}" == "true") {
                        APPLICATIONS += ',CatalogExporter';
                    }
                    if ("${params.signal_r}" == "true") {
                        APPLICATIONS += ',SignalR';
                    }
                    if ("${params.fiscal}" == "true") {
                        APPLICATIONS += ',Fiscal';
                    }

                    return APPLICATIONS;
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Revert Lab') {
            steps {
                dir("ansible") {
                    ansiblePlaybook (
                        [
                            inventory: '.../lab_r_mf.yml',
                            playbook: '.../ansible/playbooks/revert_vcenter_lab.yml',
                            installation: 'ansible',
                            colorized   : true,
                        ]
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Copy Files') {
        stage('Copy Files') {
            steps {
                dir("ansible") {
                    ansiblePlaybook (
                        [
                            inventory: '.../lab_r_mf.yml',
                            playbook: '.../ansible/playbooks/copy_tfs_builds.yml',
                            installation: 'ansible',
                            colorized   : true,
                            extraVars   : [
                                version_choice: '${version_choice}',
                                quality_choice: '${quality_choice}'
                            ]
                        ]
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Center APP') {
            steps {
                dir("ansible") {
                    ansiblePlaybook (
                        [
                            inventory: '.../lab_r_mf.yml',
                            playbook: '.../ansible/playbooks/install_secured_center_primary_appserver.yml',
                            installation: 'ansible',
                            colorized   : true,
                            extraVars   : [
                                applications: "${APPLICATIONS}",
                            ]
                        ]
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Gateway') {
            steps {
                dir("ansible") {
                    ansiblePlaybook (
                        [
                            inventory: '.../lab_r_mf.yml',
                            playbook: '.../ansible/playbooks/install_secured_gateway.yml',
                            installation: 'ansible',
                            colorized   : true,
                            extraVars   : [
                                protocol_choice: '${protocol_choice}',
                                version_choice: '${version_choice}',
                                quality_choice: '${quality_choice}',
                            ]
                        ]
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        stage('app') {
            steps {
                dir("ansible") {
                    ansiblePlaybook (
                        [
                            inventory: '.../lab_r_mf.yml',
                            playbook: '.../ansible/playbooks/install_secured_app.yml',
                            installation: 'ansible',
                            colorized   : true,
                            extraVars   : [
                                applications: "${APPLICATIONS}",
                            ]
                        ]
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        stage('EFT. Sim.') {
            parallel {
                stage('MTX') {
                    when {
                        expression {
                            params.eft_simulator_choice == 'MTX'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        dir("ansible") {
                            ansiblePlaybook (
                                [
                                    inventory: '.../lab_r_mf.yml',
                                    playbook: '.../ansible/playbooks/deploy_mtx_simulator.yml',
                                    installation: 'ansible',
                                    colorized   : true,
                                    extraVars   : [
                                       protocol_choice: '${protocol_choice}',
                                    ]
                                ]
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('EPS') {
                    when {
                        expression {
                            params.eft_simulator_choice == 'EPS'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        dir("ansible") {
                            ansiblePlaybook (
                                [
                                    inventory: '.../lab_r_mf.yml',
                                    playbook: '.../ansible/playbooks/deploy_eps_simulator.yml',
                                    installation: 'ansible',
                                    colorized   : true,
                                    extraVars   : [
                                        version_choice: '${version_choice}',
                                        quality_choice: '${quality_choice}',
                                        protocol_choice: '${protocol_choice}',
                                    ]
                                ]
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- It often happens that the pipeline falls because of a network issuesor any unexpected behaviour
- Trying to restart the pipline based on this Jenkins, shows error message like:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: APPLICATIONS for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:251)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:277)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor304.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:420)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:95)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:30)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:70)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE
```

- This failure means that Jenkins doesn't know APPLICATIONS varaiable.
- How do I take care of this varaiable and others (like $protocol_choice) in a way that in any phase Jenkinsfile "know" the varaiable and its selected value?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [Rebuilder](https://plugins.jenkins.io/rebuild/) plugin. When you set parameters, it will remember what those parameters are. When you want to rerun a job, you can select the job and there will be a new "Rebuild" button in the left hand pane which will start the job with all the parameters you used previously.

Comment: APPLICATIONS is a varaiable inside a script - it 'collects' the selected parameters and 'creates' a string from those parameters. I don't know how to convert this APPLICATIONS variable into a parameter inside parameters block. So, currently the plugins can 'remember' only the selection of the parameters beside APPLICATION variable

Comment: @M B, There are times that this plugin start over the pipeline, and times that its start from the failed stage. Why is that?